# jsPDF use Chinese fonts to build PDF from HTML

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jspdf, chinese-locale

I am using WordPress Eventin plugin which embedded jsPDF. I have successfully added Chinese fonts SimHei.ttf to jsPDF like that:

```
const jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
doc.addFont('https://server/path/Fonts/SimHei.ttf', 'SimHei', 'normal');
doc.setFont('SimHei');
doc.text("Octonyan loves jsPDF 中文字", 35, 25);
```

But I need to convert HTML to PDF like that:

```
let getContent = "<p>Octonyan loves jsPDF 中文字</p>";
doc.html(getContent, {
    callback: function () {
        doc.save(ticketname);
    },
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
});
```

It does not display Chinese to PDF.

Anyone can help output HTML to PDF.
Thank you!

- Downloaded original jsPDF to test
- Selected usable Chinese fonts
- Used fontconverter for following test
- Tried - doc.addFileToVFS("SimHei.ttf", myFont);   It also works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `compression` parameter in jsPDF is set to `false` when you are creating the object of it called `doc`. Like this:

```
const doc = new jsPDF({
  compress: false,
  orientation: 'p',
  unit: 'px',
  format: 'a4'
});
```